# At what dataset size and model complexity do you see performance bottlenecks for Generalised Linear Models?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, large-data

I am doing research into solvers for applying generalized linear models to large/big data sets and wanted to gauge the demand for these types of models.

If you are currently using them and are having serious performance bottlenecks at what size data are you having problems in terms of number of coefficients (p) or number of observations (n)?

Comment: If part of the size-related performance problem manifests as a large amount of hard disk drive activity, as memory chunks are swapped to and from disk, there is a possibility that a solid-state drive (SSD) will greatly improve performance. This will only help if you are memory-constrained which can easily be determined by watching the operating system's free RAM as the problem runs to completion on your computer.

Comment: My R package bigReg already does chunking from disk. I'm just wondering if analysts out there using GLMs for very large data sets have a great need for faster solvers - looking at developing faster algorithms. Even if you chunk data you _can_ still run into performance problems with large _p_

Comment: My point was directed at a possible hardware mitigation, not the chunking itself.